# Once I select ubuntu in grub menu, it starts ubuntu normally. But after sometimes it displays bunch of operations on black screen

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, kernel, bootloader, boot-repair

I have been using ubuntu 18.04 for past three years now, dual boot with Windows 10. Till yesterday it was fine. Today once I closed my laptop and opened again there was a message "low disk space". After that I emptied the trash and the download began again. But after that when I closed and opened again it was all stuck. So I went to switch it off directly using power button. Since then whenever I select ubuntu in grub menu it shows ubuntu logo, then suddenly starts displaying some process information instead of login page. But my windows is working fine. I tried doing everything on Internet but it didn't solve the problem. I wrote acpi = off at the end of line starting with linux in a page which appears after you press e on ubuntu option in grub. And many other methods. None worked. Please help. 
[Here you can see all the operation list I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Epyk.jpg)

Comment: Can you make a screenshot or reproduce the messages it shows instead of the login screen?

Comment: I just uploaded the link to the image. Please review it and help me.